# Set CSS custom property/variable from javascript as type String

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-variables

Consider the following scenario:

```js
document.body.style.setProperty("--text", "world")
```

```css
body::before{
  --text: "Hello";
  content: var(--text, "...");
}

body::after{
  content: var(--text, "...");
}
```

CSS is able to set a ***type*** to the variable by having the value of the *custom property* `--text` with quotes, but when done the same with javascript `setProperty` this is the outcome of the (inspected) node (in Chrome) which is without quotes, which makes it impossible to use as `content` value of a pseudo-element:

[image]

Can this somehow be done via JS using `setProperty`? (assuming the element already has a bunch of stuff in its `style` attribute which I don't want to mess with.

Comment: Does it have to be a CSS variable? Can't you just set a data-property on `body` and then use `content: attr(data-property)` on your pseudo-elements?

Comment: Yes, it **has** to be Rickard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Set it as so:

```
document.body.style.setProperty("--text", "'world'")
```

#### The problem is now this:

```js
var word = "world";

document.body.style.setProperty("--text", word)
```

```css
body::before{
  --text: "Hello";
  content: var(--text, "...");
}

body::after{
  content: var(--text, "...");
}
```

#### Which can be solved by:

```
document.body.style.setProperty("--text", JSON.stringify(word))
```

Comment: I think that should be `CSS.escape` not `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 0):

If one is utilizing data-binding properties, e.g. Knockout JS, you could set the "" string value using Template literal syntax

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="style: {'--text': self.Word() }" style='--prefix: "";'>
```

**JS**

```
self.Word = ko.observable(`"${word}"`)
```